# ADM for Amazon Kindle Fire - INVALID_SENDER

Tags: android, kindle-fire

Hi I am new to Amazon Kindle Fire,

I downloaded a sample code snsmobilepush.zip from [docs.aws.amazon.com](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-adm.html#registration-id-adm)

and when i am following to get [Obtaining ADM Credentials](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/device-messaging/tech-docs/02-obtaining-adm-credentials)

**To create an API Key,**
 I have expoted and created myapp.keystore file. When I am exporting, MD5 is taken like below
[image]

and API Key Name : test_profile_com.mycompany.kindletest
Package : com.mycompany.kindletest
Signature : 19:BB:B2:9C:91:0E:92:2D:8E:CC:9E:16:9E:F0:EE:34 (This is taken from above image while exporting) and press add button to create API_KEY and pasted in string.xml

I am getting error **code INVALID_SENDER** in the method onRegistrationError(final String string){.

Where am I wrong, Can you please anyone tell me ?

and to work ADM...

1. Do we need publish the app in [Amazon App Store](https://developer.amazon.com/myapps.html) ?
2. Is it necessary Server side implementation for testing ?
3. Is it necessary to create api_key.txt in Assets folder ?

Comment: Any luck, I am getting same error.

Comment: No luck saleem ,please inform me if you get it

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by exporting the apk from ecllipse and then install manually on my Kindle. Previously I was trying it from ecllipse.

To manually install apk on the kindle try following command

```
adb install -i com.amazon.venezia YOUR_APK_NAME.apk
```